# How to export all deleted data from tally using XML

Tags: tally

I want to export all deleted masters and vouchers from tally using XML. I got deleted data when download directly from tally. Structure of deleted data portion looks like

```
</BODY>
 <ELDELETEDLEDNAME>Test Ledger</ELDELETEDLEDNAME>
 <ELDELETEDFLAG>(Deleted)</ELDELETEDFLAG>
 <ELDELETEDLEDNAME>Testing</ELDELETEDLEDNAME>
 <ELDELETEDFLAG>(Deleted)</ELDELETEDFLAG>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: I didn't understand , what you want exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to export all data from external application. I want to export list of all deleted masters such as stock item, ledger, group, stock category from tally using XML. Also I want to export list of deleted vouchers.

Comment: Is edit log enabled in Tally?

Comment: Yes, edit log enable in tally prime 2.1

Comment: I provided answer, If solution works mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all vouchers use below XML

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
        <ID>CusVouchers</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <!-- * Supports only xml format -->
                <SVViewName>Accounting Voucher View</SVViewName>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">01-Apr-2021</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">31-Mar-2022</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="Yes" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CusVouchers">
                        <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
                        <FETCH> *</FETCH>
                        <IncludeDeleted>Yes</IncludeDeleted>
                        <FILTER>DeleteFilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="DeleteFilter">$ISDELETED = Yes</SYSTEM>
    
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Use want to get deletes Masters then replace the type with mastertype

Ex: if you want deleted Ledgers then `<TYPE>Ledgers</TYPE>`
[image]
This is what used in TDL

Comment: It works properly for deleted vouchers. But, it is not working for master section.

Comment: ```<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER><VERSION>1</VERSION><TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST><TYPE>Collection</TYPE><ID>CusLedgers</ID></HEADER>
    <BODY><DESC>
  <STATICVARIABLES><SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT></STATICVARIABLES>
  <TDL><TDLMESSAGE>
   <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="Yes" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CusLedgers"><TYPE>Ledger</TYPE><FETCH> *</FETCH><IncludeDeleted>Yes</IncludeDeleted><FILTER>DFltr</FILTER></COLLECTION>
   <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="DFltr">$ISDELETED = Yes</SYSTEM>
  </TDLMESSAGE></TDL>
 </DESC></BODY>
</ENVELOPE>```

Comment: I tried fetching Deleted Ledgers collection in default TDL , its also not working I believe this feature is not implemented fully , check with Tally support team